# Pester unit testing function with Mandatory=True

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, pester

I'm learning slowly using the wonderful Pester unit testing for Powershell for a while now. I'm kind of stuck around the usage of checking if my function can run "if not supplied any mandatory input into a function." which is giving me a red light here and wanted to achieve a green test result and move on coding.

So I have a function as follows.

```
function Code()
{     
param(
  [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$SourceLocation)
return "Hello from $SourceLocation"
}
```

my test script is executed with the following checks
...

```
$moduleName = 'Code';
Describe $moduleName {         
      Context "$Function - Returns a result " {
          It "does something useful with just $Function function name" {
            $true | Should Be $true
          }
      }

      Context "$Function - Returns with no input " {
        It "with no input returns Mandatory value expected" {
           Code | Should Throw
        }
      }

      Context "$Function - Returns some output" {
          It "with a name returns the standard phrase with that name" {
              Code "Venus" | Should Be "Hello from Venus"
          }
          It "with a name returns something that ends with name" {
              Code "Mars" | Should Match ".*Mars"
          }
      }

  } #End Describe
```

my output from AppVeyor shows this outcome which the [+] are green colours and [-] is a red colour which is what I'm avoiding the best I can.

```
 Describing Code
    Context Code - Returns a result 
      [+] does something useful with just Code function name 16ms
    Context Code - Returns with no input 
      [-] with no input returns Mandatory value expected 49ms
        Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: SourceLocation.
        at <ScriptBlock>, C:\projects\code\Code.Tests.ps1: line 117
        117:            Code | Should Throw

    Context Code - Returns some output
      [+] with a name returns the standard phrase with that name 23ms
      [+] with a name returns something that ends with name 11ms
```

Any help is appreciated as I would like a green condition there as I'm not sure how to overcome certain types of message responses from Powershell and translate this into unit tests...

Comment: [`Should` tests for Throw and Not Throw need a scriptblock as input](https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki/Should#throw) so try `{Code} | Should Throw`

Comment: Oh what do you know... it works! Thanks for that @TessellatingHeckler

Answer (score 2):

Per the comment from TessellatingHeckler, your code isn't working because in order to test for `Throw` you need to pipe the `Should` cmdlet a scriptblock `{ }`:

```
{Code} | Should Throw
```

It's worth noting however that (when testing for a mandatory parameter) this works OK in AppVeyor because PowerShell is running in a non-interactive console (`PowerShell.exe -noninteractive`). If you try to run your Pester tests locally, your tests will seemingly be interrupted as you get prompted for input.

There's a couple of ways around this, one is to just run your tests locally using PowerShell in noninteractive mode:

```
PowerShell.exe -noninteractive {Invoke-Pester}
```

Another is to pass the parameter an explicit `$null` or empty value (with the caveat that you can actually have a mandatory string parameter that accepts `$null` and this solution won't work necessarily with all other parameter types):

```
It "with no input returns Mandatory value expected" {
    {Code $null} | Should Throw
}
```

However it is worth noting that these two solutions throw different exception messages, and you should further test for an explicit message for the `Throw` so that your test doesn't pass if the code is failing for some other reason. E.g:

**Running with -noninteractive**

```
It "with no input returns Mandatory value expected" {
    {Code} | Should Throw 'Cannot process command because of one or more missing mandatory parameters: SourceLocation.'
}
```

**Passing it $null**

```
It "with no input returns Mandatory value expected" {
    {Code $null} | Should Throw "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'SourceLocation' because it is an empty string."
}
```

---

In summary this is only a complex issue for this specific scenario because your parameter is mandatory and you're testing for its absence.

Testing for exceptions is generally a simple process of:

```
{ some code } | should Throw 'message'
```

And works fine in both an interactive and non-interactive console.